Gain bandwidth calculation of two stage op-amp
I want to design a two stage single ended OTA without using a Miller compensation capacitance.
Every source that I have examined gives a design example with a compensation capacitance.
Hence, they calculate the gain bandwidth by using that capacitance as shown below.
GB=gm1/Cc
How can I calculate the gain bandwidth of the op-amp shown below?


Gain-bandwidth is a concept that only works for a dominant-pole compensated amplifier.  Are you asking how to calculate the open-loop gain?

Due to dominant pole, overall gain of the amplifier reaches unity gain at a ceratin frequency. By placing compansation capacitor between T4 and T6 (at the gate of T6) op-amp they create a dominant pole. And calculate the gain bandwidth as shown above. But without the capacitor, how can I calculate it? @JohnD

The concept of gain bandwidth, where the closed-loop bandwidth can be determined by dividing the GBW by the desired closed-loop gain only works if there's a dominant-pole compensation.  Otherwise, gain-bandwidth does not exist.  You'll have flat gain out until your transistors start to roll off, where you'll have a bunch of poles with lots of phase shift.  So GBW doesn't apply.

Referring the link below, did not they find the pole of the same amplifier? @JohnD https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/535765/complex-conjugate-poles-for-ota-unity-gain

Even without any specific Miller feedback there is only one node with any significant voltage changes and that is the gate of T6. if the device models have realistic capacitances for T6 that node will probably dominate and give a meaningful GBW.

@KevinWhite Sure, that’s possible but I wouldn’t tape anything out relying on that without lots of analysis and simulation.  To the OP, yes, they found a pole, but finding a pole and having a GBW are different and one doesn’t necessarily lead to the other.
